# Why are lil_matrix and dok_matrix so slow compared to common dict of dicts?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to iteratively build sparse matrices, and noticed that there are two suitable options for this according to the SciPy documentation:

[LiL matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.lil_matrix):

> class scipy.sparse.lil_matrix(arg1, shape=None, dtype=None,
>   copy=False)[source] Row-based linked list sparse matrix
>
> This is an efficient structure for constructing sparse matrices
>   incrementally.

[DoK matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.dok_matrix):

> class scipy.sparse.dok_matrix(arg1, shape=None, dtype=None,
>   copy=False)[source] Dictionary Of Keys based sparse matrix.
>
> This is an efficient structure for constructing sparse matrices
>   incrementally.

But when I'm running benchmarks comparing to building a dictionary of dictionary of values (which later can be easily converted to sparse matrix), the latter turns out to be about 10-20 times faster than using any of the sparse matrix models:

```
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix, lil_matrix
from timeit import timeit
from collections import defaultdict

def common_dict(rows, cols):
    freqs = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
    for row, col in zip(rows, cols):
        freqs[row][col] += 1

    return freqs

def dok(rows, cols):
    freqs = dok_matrix((1000,1000))
    for row, col in zip(rows, cols):
        freqs[row,col] += 1

    return freqs

def lil(rows, cols):
    freqs = lil_matrix((1000,1000))
    for row, col in zip(rows, cols):
        freqs[row,col] += 1

    return freqs


def benchmark():
    cols = range(1000)
    rows = range(1000)

    res = timeit("common_dict({},{})".format(rows, cols), 
                 "from __main__ import common_dict", 
                 number=100)

    print("common_dict: {}".format(res))

    res = timeit("dok({},{})".format(rows, cols), 
                 "from __main__ import dok", 
                 number=100)

    print("dok: {}".format(res))

    res = timeit("lil({},{})".format(rows, cols), 
                 "from __main__ import lil", 
                 number=100)

    print("lil: {}".format(res))
```

Results:

```
benchmark()

common_dict: 0.11778324202168733
dok: 2.2927695910912007
lil: 1.3541790939634666
```

What is it that causes such a overhead for the matrix models, and is there some way to speed it up? Are there use cases where either dok or lil are to prefer over a common dict of dicts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When I change your `+=` to just `=` for your 2 sparse arrays:

```
for row, col in zip(rows, cols):
    #freqs[row,col] += 1
    freqs[row,col] = 1
```

their respective times are cut in half.  What's consuming the most time is the indexing.  With `+=` it is has to do both a `__getitem__` and a `__setitem__`.

When the docs say that `dok` and `lil` are better for iterative construction they mean that it's easier to expand their underlying data structures than for the other formats.

When I try to make a `csr` matrix with your code, I get a:

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:690: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
>     SparseEfficiencyWarning)

and 30x slower speed.

So the speed claims are relative to formats like `csr`, not relative to pure Python or `numpy` structures.

You might want to look at the Python code for `dok_matrix.__get_item__` and `dok_matrix.__set_item__` to see what happens when you do `freq[r,c]`.

---

A faster way to construct your `dok` would be:

```
freqs = dok_matrix((1000,1000))
d = dict()
for row, col in zip(rows, cols):
    d[(row, col)] = 1
freqs.update(d)
```

taking advantage of the fact that a `dok` is a subclassed dictionary.  Note that `dok` matrix is not a dictionary of dictionaries.  Its keys are tuples like `(50,50)`.

Another fast way of constructing the same sparse array is:

```
freqs = sparse.coo_matrix((np.ones(1000,int),(rows,cols)))
```

In other words, since you already have the `rows` and `cols` arrays (or ranges), calculate the corresponding `data` array, and THEN construct the sparse array.

But if you must perform sparse operations on your matrix between incremental growth steps, then `dok` or `lil` may be your best choices.

---

Sparse matricies were developed for linear algebra problems, such as solving a linear equation with a large sparse matrix.  I used them years ago in MATLAB to solve finite difference problems.  For that work the calculation friendly `csr` format is the ultimate goal, and the `coo` format was a convenient initialization format.

Now many of the SO scipy sparse questions arise from `scikit-learn` and text analysis problems.  They are also used in a biological database files.  But still the `(data),(row,col)` definition method works best.

So sparse matrices were never intended for fast incremental creation.  The traditional Python structures like dictionaries and lists are much better for that.

---

Here's a faster `dok` iteration that takes advantage of its dictionary methods.  `update` seems to work as fast as on a plain dictionary. `get` is about 3x faster the equivalent indexing (`freq[row,col]`).  Indexing probably uses `get`, but must have a lot of overhead.

```
def fast_dok(rows, cols):
    freqs = dok_matrix((1000,1000))
    for row, col in zip(rows,cols):
         i = freqs.get((row,col),0)
         freqs.update({(row,col):i+1})
    return freqs
```

Skipping the `get`, and just doing

```
         freqs.update({(row,col): 1)
```

is even faster - faster than the defaultdict of defaultdict example, and nearly as fast as simple dictionary initialization (`{(r, c):1 for r,c in zip(rows, cols)}`)

Comment: On my system, `fast_dok` is about four times slower than `common_dict` and eight times slower than `tuple_dict`, which is what I called your first example.

Comment: Cont.: I am not sure, why: it might be because you create a `dict` for every pair, or maybe at the time of writing `dok_matrix` didn't override `get()`, and now it does? Fortunately, `update()` is not yet overridden, so the first solution works and it is very fast. One caveat: any `0`s in the `defaultdict` will also be stored by the resulting `dok_matrix`; luckily, one can convert the data to e.g. `csr_matrix` and then call `eliminate_zeros()`.

Comment: Py3.6 has new `dict` code (default ordered etc), so there could be speed changes.

Answer (score 1):

There are various reasons why your test is not fair. Firstly, you're including the overhead of constructing the sparse matrices as part of your timed loop.

Secondly, and arguably more importantly, you should use data structures as they are designed to be used, with operations on the whole array at once. That is, rather than iterating over the rows and columns and adding 1 each time, simply add 1 to the whole array.

Comment: Fair enough on your first point. I did some quick tests, and the performance difference didn't alter too much. My main thought was that initializing the defaultdict would be an somewhat of an equivalent initialization, and since I'm mostly interested in the performance of incremental buildup, I didn't create the coo_matrix as a last step.

Regarding your second point, though, I'm not quite sure I understand. What do you mean by adding 1 to the whole array?

Comment: OP isn't adding 1 to the whole array.  He's adding 1 to the main diagonal, in effect constructing a `sparse.eye(1000)`.  But I think that's just an example of iterative assignment, not the final goal.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes exactly, I should have been more clear in my example. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @hpaulj yeah, quite right. The main point though is that you shouldn't iterate over a matrix (or a numpy) array. If you do find you have to do that, you've lost all the advantages, as the question notes.