# Which format of scipy.sparse is best for this type of matrix generation and use?

Tags: python, scipy, vectorization, sparse-matrix

I have a data file that encodes information about nonzero elements of a large sparse boolean matrix. This matrix does not have any particular structure, i.e. it's not diagonal or block etc. Each row of the file determines one element. Right now I use the following loop to populate the matrix:

```
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix

nRows = 30000
nCols = 600000

data = dok_matrix((nRows,nCols), dtype=np.int8)

with open('input.txt','r') as fraw:
    for line in fraw:
        ## Figure out iRow and iCol to set to 1 from line
        data[iRow,iCol] = 1
```

This is working but it's very slow. Is there a different type of `scipy.sparse` matrix that is more optimal?

'Optimal' means the speed of both matrix generation and access of row and column blocks of the matrix, e.g. vector operations like

```
someRows = data[rowIndex1:rowIndex2,]
someColumns = data[,colIndex1:colIndex2]
```

Does the answer change if memory is more important than speed?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For incremental additions like this `dok` is as good as it gets.  It is really a dictionary that stores the value at a tuple: `(iRow,iCol)`.  So storing and fetching depends on the basic Python dictinary efficiency.

The only one that is good for incremental additions is `lil` which stores the data as 2 lists of lists.

Another approach is to collect you data in 3 lists, and construct the matrix at the end.  A start for that is `coo` and its `(data,(i,j))` input method.

Dense `numpy` arrays are loaded from a file with `genfromtxt` or `loadtxt`.  Both of those read the file, line by line, collecting values in a list of lists, with array creation at the end.

What's the speed like if you just read the file and parse the values - without saving anything to the `dok`?  That would give you an idea of how much time is actually spent adding the data to the matrix.

---

Another possbility is to store the values directly to a generic dictionary, and use that to create the `dok`.

```
In [60]: adict=dict()

In [61]: for i in np.random.randint(1000,size=(2000,)):
    adict[(i,i)]=1
   ....:     

In [62]: dd=sparse.dok_matrix((1000,1000),dtype=np.int8)

In [63]: dd.update(adict)

In [64]: dd.A
Out[64]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ..., 
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1]], dtype=int8)
```

That is quite a bit faster than directly updating the `dok`.

```
In [66]: %%timeit 
for i in np.random.randint(1000,size=(2000,)):
    adict[(i,i)]=1
dd.update(adict)
   ....: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.32 ms per loop

In [67]: %%timeit 
for i in np.random.randint(1000,size=(2000,)):
    dd[i,i]=1
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 35.6 ms per loop
```

There must be some overhead in updating the `dok` that I wasn't taking into account.

I just realized that I'd suggest this `update` method once before:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27771335/901925
`Why are lil_matrix and dok_matrix so slow compared to common dict of dicts?`

Comment: I think, although I did not verify it, that the bulk of the time is spent at the `data[iRow,iCol] = 1` assignment. Calculating `iRow` and `iCol` consists of getting indices of elements of string lists.

Comment: I added some notes about adding the values to a generic dictionary, and then using `update` to create the `dok`.