# Efficient incremental sparse matrix in python / scipy / numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

Is there a way in Python to have an efficient incremental update of sparse matrix?

```
 H = lil_matrix((n,m))
 for (i,j) in zip(A,B):
   h(i,j) += compute_something
```

It seems that such a way to build a sparse matrix is quite slow (`lil_matrix` is the fastest sparse matrix type for that).

Is there a way (like using dict of dict or other kind of approaches) to efficiently build the sparse matrix H?

Comment: How large are `H`, `A` and `B`?

Comment: The size of the sparse matrix is about 100000 x 100000. So dim(A) can be close to 10^6.

Answer (score 4):

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/27771335/901925 I explore incremental matrix assignment.

`lol` and `dok` are the recommended formats if you want to change values. `csr` will give you an efficiency warning, and `coo` does not allow indexing.

But I also found that `dok` indexing is slow compared to regular dictionary indexing.  So for many changes it is better to build a plain dictionary (with the same tuple indexing), and build the `dok` matrix from  that.

But if you can calculate the `H` data values with a fast `numpy` vector operation, as opposed to iteration, it is best to do so, and construct the sparse matrix from that (e.g. `coo` format).  In fact even with iteration this would be faster:

```
 h = np.zeros(A.shape)
 for k, (i,j) in enumerate(zip(A,B)):
    h[k] = compute_something 
 H = sparse.coo_matrix((h, (A, B)), shape=(n,m))
```

e.g.

```
In [780]: A=np.array([0,1,1,2]); B=np.array([0,2,2,1])
In [781]: h=np.zeros(A.shape)
In [782]: for k, (i,j) in enumerate(zip(A,B)):
    h[k] = i+j+k
   .....:     
In [783]: h
Out[783]: array([ 0.,  4.,  5.,  6.])
In [784]: M=sparse.coo_matrix((h,(A,B)),shape=(4,4))
In [785]: M
Out[785]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [786]: M.A
Out[786]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  9.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  6.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Note that the (1,2) value is the sum 4+5.  That's part of the `coo` to `csr` conversion.

In this case I could have calculated `h` with:

```
In [791]: A+B+np.arange(A.shape[0])
Out[791]: array([0, 4, 5, 6])
```

so there's no need for iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, do not use `csr_matrix` or `csc_matrix`, as they are going to be even more slower than `lil_matrix`, if you construct them incrementally. The Dictionary of Key based sparse matrix is exactly what you are looking for

```
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix
S = dok_matrix((5, 5), dtype=np.float32)
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        S[i,j] = i+j    # Update elements
```

Comment: I found in other SO questions that indexing a plain dictionary (same keys) is faster than indexing a dok dictionary.

Comment: I've tested lil, csc, csr and dok matrices. lil_matrix was the fastest by far.

Comment: I believe that. If you look at the implementation of scipy's dok format, it is essentially a wrapper over dict. Moreover, the __getitem__ and __setitem__ methods of dok are written in pure Python so indexing them will introduce more overhead. However, compared to other sparse formats, dok is relatively cheaper to iterate over as item access is algorithmically still O(1)/constant. Honestly, I think sparse matrices are not really meant to be iterated over.

Answer (score 0):

A faster way would be:

```
H_ij = compute_something_vectorized()
H = coo_matrix((H_ij, (A, B))).tocsr()
```

The data for duplicate coordinates are then summed, see the [docs for `coo_matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html).

Comment: This should be best IF the vectorized function can be made.

Comment: I'd like to vectorize this function but I'm not sure I can !